# How do I loop PHP array in array?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript array that I can loop:

```
let events = [{
      id: '2',
      eventName: 'ones',
      sessions: [{
        id: '1245',
        status: false
      }, {
        id: '2125',
        status: true
      }]
}];
```

Im accessing each event like this and setting it into a new row of a table:

```
// $tour_events its the array of events
<?php foreach ($events as $key => $event_prop) { ?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">NAME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $event_prop->id; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $event_prop->eventName; ?>
            </td>
```

I want to access the data inside of sessions to create another table, I have tried this but it's not working:

( Insite the other foreach() )

```
<?php foreach ($events['sessions'] as $key2 => $value) { ?>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">SESSION ID</th>
                <th scope="col">SESSION STATUS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $value->id; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $value->status; ?>
                </td>
```

Comment: Are you sending this `events` array to the server?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Where does the JavaScript come into this?

Comment: JavaScript runs in the users browsers, PHP runs on your servers. It's unclear how your code snippets are connected.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes! But seems like only the info outside sessions

Comment: @PrateikDarji Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in: ...

Comment: try using `$sessions = json_decode(json_encode($events['sessions]));` and then use `$sesstions` variable in foreach loop

Comment: You're accessing the other properties like `$event_prop->eventName` so why would you do it any different for the `sessions` property?  `$event_prop->sessions`

Comment: @PatrickQ Umm makes sense, how could i access especific propierty in sessions like 'status'?

Comment: The same way you already are.  You just have to change what you're using in the `foreach` part to match the way you're doing it for the other properties.

Answer (score 4):

`sessions` is a property the same as `id` or `eventName`, so you access it the same way

```
<?php foreach ($event_prop->sessions as $key2 => $value) { ?>
```

Everything else stays the same